# jquery doesn't recognize dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I am successfully able to generate a list of products as checkboxes through vb and adding those to `<ul>` tag

```
<input type="text" id="searchText" />
<input type="button" value="Search" id="weSearch" />
<div>                                                                                     
 <ul runat="server" id="ulVal" style="list-style-type:none"/></ul>                       
</div>

Dim brandname As String
        Dim brandid As Integer
        Dim build As New StringBuilder()
        Dim msql As New MySqlConnection()
        msql.ConnectionString = "Server=192.168.1.230;Database=cable_tv_reporting1;Uid=root;Pwd=master!!@"
        msql.Open()
        Select Case msql.State
            Case System.Data.ConnectionState.Open

                Exit Select
            Case System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed

                Response.Write("Connection Closed")
                Exit Select
            Case Else
                Exit Select
        End Select
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("select brandID, brandName from cap_brand where isActive=1;", msql)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            brandid = Convert.ToInt32(reader(0))
            brandname = reader(1).ToString()
            build.Append("<li><input type='checkbox' name ='brands' id='" & brandid & "' value='" & brandid & "'/><label for='" & brandid & "'>" & brandname & "</label></li>")

        End While
        ulVal.InnerHtml = build.ToString()
```

the problem is that jquery does not recongize the html that I have generated dynamically

```
$('document').ready(function () {
                                                                                                                    $('#weSearch').on('click', function () {
                                                                                                                        var counted = 0;
                                                                                                                        var boxes = $('#ulVal').find(':checkbox');
                                                                                                                        boxes.each(function () {
                                                                                                                            counted++ ;
                                                                                                                        });
                                                                                                                        alert(counted);
                                                                                                                    });
                                                                                                                });
```

the result that i get is always 0 instead of the actual number of products. How can I fix this

Comment: You should paste the generated HTML, and probably remove your database's root password

Comment: Do you get any console error?

Comment: I do get 2 errors but I can't seem to figure out how to see what the errors are. using jquery debugger

Comment: @ra_ie_darkness How about pressing `F12` and checking the console..?

Comment: found the error and solved the issue, thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, turns out I had to look at the generated html. The id of the `ul` was  changing because of the tab container. Thank you for helping